# FIND / SEARCH within Formula line

Tags: excel, search

I was wondering if it was possible to use the Search / Find formula within a formula line.
Just to check if the formula used is correct (linked correctly.)

So the "controle" formula would have to Search for a word within a formula code used in another column

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, just add the function `FORMULATEXT()` to the reference in the [within_text] argument of `SEARCH` or `FIND`

```
=FIND(E2,FORMULATEXT(C2),1)
```

[image: illustration]